# Predict using Negative Binomial model in SAS

Tags: sas, poisson, binomial-coefficients

I built a Poisson model for count data in SAS but since the model had issues of overdispersion and the ratio of deviance to degree of freedom was too high (32+), I switched to a Negative Binomial model. The code I used -

```
ods html file = "output.html";
proc genmod data = train_data;
    class &class_var./ param = glm;
    model &dependent_var. = &selected_variable./ dist=nb;
    OUTPUT OUT=OUTREG1 P=PREDICT COOKSD=COOKD;
    store out = out_model;
run;
```

From what I have read up online so far, the parameter estimates get saved in the object `out_model`. I wanted to use this `out_model` to predict the output for my test data set; like the `predict()` function in R , so I used the following code

```
proc plm source = out_model;
  score data = test_data out= pred_outp;
run;
```

The proc above produced the dataset but I need the model fit statistics like 
-2 Log Likelihood, AIC, BIC, Pearson Chi-Square, Pearson Chi-Square/DF to see how the model performs on test data. Any ideas around how to calculate or display those statistics.